# How To Get Rscript To Function For Collaborators

Tags: r, unix, command-line-interface, rscript

I'm helping in developing a pipeline for researchers and one of the steps require parsing of a large Excel spreadsheet in order to subset and export a file based on some key columns and parameter ranges.

I've written the code and have the repo hosted via **GitLab** and available for cloning within my organization.

However my collaborators have been unable to get the code to run and I've gone over a session via Teams to see whether they were cloning the repo correctly, had the correct input file and whether they were entering the command and arguments correctly.

Using `Rscript` the command is running absolutely correctly on my *Biolinux* terminal however for unknown reasons my collaborators keep getting odd error messages that seem to be related to the terminal and not R:

> Error in !colargs: invalid argument type
> Calls:  ... col_spec_standardise-> as.col_spec->my_cols->
> Execution halted

Any suggestions on figuring out what exactly is going on?

Edit: Below is the code I'm using

```
#!/usr/bin/env Rscript
args = commandArgs(trailingOnly = T)
# args = list("allDB_03282022.txt", "ATL", 2018, 1, 12, "SURRG_ATL_2018_JAN_DEC.csv")

# Import magrittr expressions
`%>%` <- magrittr::`%>%`
`%<>%` <- magrittr::`%<>%`

# Define function my_cols
my_cols <- function(..., .default = readr::col_guess()) {
  dots <- rlang::enexprs(...)
  colargs <- purrr::flatten_chr(unname(
    purrr::imap(dots, ~ {
      colnames <- rlang::syms(.x)
      colnames <- colnames[colnames != rlang::sym("c")]
      coltypes <- purrr::rep_along(colnames, .y)
      purrr::set_names(coltypes, colnames)
    })
  ))
  readr::cols(!!!colargs, .default = .default)
}

surrg_all <- readr::read_tsv(file = args[1], col_names = TRUE, na = "NA",
                             col_types = my_cols(D = c(TEST_DATE, SPECIMEN_COLLECTION_DATE, DATE_WGSID_ASSIGNED, DATE_RESULT_RELEASED),
                                                 # f = c(GC_FACILITY_CODE, SEQUENCING_LAB, GCWGS_DL_FROM_ARLN, SHIPPED_ARLN,
                                                 # ARLN_PHL, JURISDICTION_PHL, PATIENT_GENDER, SPECIMEN_TYPE, 
                                                 # BETALAC_RESULT_CODE, SPECIMEN_QUALITY, YR_COLLECT, MTH_COLLECT)
                             ))

# Change select variable types to factor
surrg_all %<>% 
  dplyr::mutate(dplyr::across(c(GC_FACILITY_CODE, YR_COLLECT, MTH_COLLECT), as.factor))

# remove rows with NA in any of the variables GC_FACILITY_CODE, YR_COLLECT or MTH_COLLECT
surrg_all %<>% tidyr::drop_na(GC_FACILITY_CODE, YR_COLLECT, MTH_COLLECT)

# Use forcats::fct_collapse() to assign levels to shared GC_FACILITY_CODE factors
surrg_all %<>% dplyr::mutate(GC_FACILITY_CODE2 = forcats::fct_collapse(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE,
                                                                       ALB = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^ALB")))),
                                                                       ANC = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^ANC")))),
                                                                       ATL = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^ATL")))),
                                                                       BAL = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^BAL")))),
                                                                       BHM = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^BHM")))),
                                                                       BOS = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^BOS")))),
                                                                       BUF = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^BUF")))),
                                                                       CAM = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^CAM")))),
                                                                       CHI = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^CHI")))),
                                                                       CLE = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^CLE")))),
                                                                       COL = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^COL")))),
                                                                       DAL = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^DAL")))),
                                                                       DEN = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^DEN")))),
                                                                       GRB = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^GRB")))),
                                                                       HON = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^HON")))),
                                                                       IND = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^IND")))),
                                                                       JAC = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^JAC")))),
                                                                       KAZ = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^KAZ")))),
                                                                       KCY = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^KCY")))),
                                                                       LA = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^LA")))),
                                                                       LVG = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^LVG")))),
                                                                       MIA = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^MIA")))),
                                                                       MIL = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^MIL")))),
                                                                       MIN = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^MIN")))),
                                                                       NOR = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^NOR")))),
                                                                       NYC = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^NYC")))),
                                                                       ORA = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^ORA")))),
                                                                       PHI = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^PHI")))),
                                                                       PHX = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^PHX")))),
                                                                       PON = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^PON")))),
                                                                       POR = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^POR")))),
                                                                       SDG = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^SDG")))),
                                                                       SEA = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^SEA")))),
                                                                       SFO = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^SFO")))),
                                                                       TRP = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^TRP")))),
                                                                       WDC = as.character(unique(subset(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, stringr::str_detect(surrg_all$GC_FACILITY_CODE, "^WDC"))))
), .after = GC_FACILITY_CODE) # %>% View()

# Export output file
surrg_all %>%
  dplyr::filter(GC_FACILITY_CODE2 == args[2], YR_COLLECT == args[3], MTH_COLLECT %in% args[[4]]:args[[5]]) %>% 
  dplyr::select(!GC_FACILITY_CODE2) %>% 
  readr::write_csv(file = args[[6]] , quote = "none", na = "")
```

Comment: We would probably need to see the code.  One potential problem would be that your collaborators do not have all the relevant dependencies.

Comment: @DaveArmstrong Code has been added. You may be right that it is a dependency issue and I need to learn how to install required dependencies on all collaborator sessions.

Comment: I think the `pacman` package has functions for installing dependencies. Get everyone to install that, and then you can `pacman::p_load()` the rest of the packages. (Assuming their installation is straightforward...)